# Checkbox in Express

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm currently trying to parse over checkbox values into an array via express/ejs.

Currently, a user is supposed to fill in a form like this and thick a check box:
Answer:  Checkbox:

I want to parse the data such that I got two arrays from the inputs:

answer = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4"]
checkbox = [checked, unchecked, unchecked, unchecked]

Problem is, express only parses through checked checkboxes and not the unchecked values (so all i get is checkbox = "checked").

How do I get express to log the "unchecked" values as well? I've considered setting value = true/false depending on whether the checkbox is checked, but I can't figure out how to check that in ejs.

Thank you!

JS

```
router.post(`/`, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect(`/`);
})
```

EJS

```
<form action="/question" method="post">
        <label for="sessionName">Session Name</label><input type="text" name="sessionName">
        <div class="question">
            <label for="question">Question: </label><input type="textarea" name="question">
            <ul>
                <li><label for="answer">Answer 1: </label><input type="textarea" name="answer"><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1"></li>
                <li><label for="answer">Answer 2: </label><input type="textarea" name="answer"><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1"></li>
                <li><label for="answer">Answer 3: </label><input type="textarea" name="answer"><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1"></li>
                <li><label for="answer">Answer 4: </label><input type="textarea" name="answer"><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Create Session">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Form will only send the checked values to the node server, so Express cannot know what unchecked values are, nor what were the corresponding "strings", labels or whatever.

I guess you'll have to work your own mechanism with some hidden input and values updated just before the submit occurs (form.onsubmit = ...) in order to create those arrays your need.